# How to draw floating pie charts on an existing plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot multiple pie charts over an existing plot using absolute coordinates.

I went through the add_axes method and also the [AxesGrid toolikt](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html) but couldn't find a solution.

To be more specific, I want to draw pie charts over a geographical map using the basemap module.

Comment: Could you post an image of the result you want?

Comment: Could you post your solution? Thanks.